# Java OOP concept for library model

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

I am new to Java and I need some help implementing OOP rules for projects that are similar to the Library model (Car rental model).

I have 2 classes:

- `public class Book`
- `public class Customer`

Simply put, my classes look like this:

```
public class Customer
{
    public String fullName;
    public String address;

    /* Constructor */
    public Customer(String fullName, String address) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
        this.address = address;
    }}
```

and

```
public class Book
{
    private String bookName;
    private int pageNumber;
    public Customer customer;   //I think this needs to be fixed

    /* Constructor */
    public Book(String bookName, int pageNumber, Customer customer) {
        this.bookName = bookName;
        this.pageNumber = pageNumber;
        // ... There I am not sure how to do something like: this.customer = customer ...

    // there should be another constructor without customer as a parameter but i can deal with that cuz its easy
    }}
```

Each instance of the Customer class represents a person who borrowed the book. Now what I am struggling to implement is: **How do I pass an instance of Customer class as a parameter for a constructor of the Book class?** I would like something like this:

```
// Constructor in Class Book:
public Book(String bookName, int pageNumber, Customer customer) {
    this.bookName = bookName;
    this.pageNumber = pageNumber;
    this.customer = customer;  //I think this needs to be fixed
}
```

Another question is how do I create a record of a book boorowed by Sarah Connor living in London? Is this implementation correct Book book1 = new Book("The Hobbit", 300, "Sarah Connor", "London")?

Comment: *"I think this needs to be fixed"* - **why?**

Comment: Apart from a wrong name (Car instead of Book) your second constructor is correct.

Comment: What's the problem with what you already have?

Comment: what seems to be the problem?

Comment: So it is correct? It will do? But then how do I declare some book via its constructor? For example lets say a man called Mike living in London borrowed a book. How do I write that record? Like this: 
Book book1 = new Book("Harry Potter", 500, "Mike", "London")?

Comment: Actually, in my opinion, what you have is counter-intuitive. Your classes imply that a book only exists if a customer has borrowed it.

Comment: @theblitz You are right, I would have 2 constructors for the Book Class - one without customer and one with a customer as a parameter.

Comment: I'd rather have some `Borrow` class referencing a borrowed `Book` and a borrowing `Customer` .

Comment: @AlexandraLvova "But then how do I declare some book via its constructor?" <- you first construct your Customer and then pass him into the constructor. 2 lines.

Comment: IMO The Book does not need to know about the Customer but the Customer must know what books he/she borrow. So having a customer in Book constructor seems not in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Basic solution

Basically, your approach was completely correct:

```
 public Book(String bookName, int pageNumber, Customer customer) {
        this.bookName = bookName;
        this.pageNumber = pageNumber;
        this.customer = customer;
 }
```

However, as your comment shows, you are still lacking some *very* basic understanding of Java. Let's recap what you tried:

```
Book book1 = new Book("Harry Potter", 500, "Mike", "London");
```

Why wouldn't this work?
First, you pass in 4 parameters instead of 3. But let's assume that was a typo and ignore `"London"`. Still, there is an issue: `"Mike"` is a `String`, but your constructor expects a `Customer`. Hence, your code should look like this:

```
Customer mike = new Customer("Mike Malony", "N13BJ London");
Book book1 = new Book("Harry Potter", 500, mike);
```

Since you asked in the comments, this can be done in one line as well:

```
Book book1 = new Book("Harry Potter", 500, new Customer("Mike", "London"));
```

## Further issues and advice

Now your issue seems solved, but your code still isn't very... versatile. The reason is that your model is severely limited: you can only ever instantiate a `Book` if you pass in a `Customer`. But most libraries I know can have books that are not currently borrowed. Also, whatever your `pageNumber` seems to represent (a bookmark, possibly?), I assume an untouched book doesn't need this information. I would therefore suggest this:

```
public Book(String bookName) {
    this.bookName = bookName;
    this.pageNumber = 0;      // 0    => no page bookmarked
    this.customer = null;     // null => book is available
}
```

Now you need a way to hand out a book to a customer and also to check its status. I suggest:

```
public void lend(Customer customer) {
    this.customer = customer;
}

public void receiveBack() {
    customer = null;
    pageNumber = 0;
}

public boolean isAvailable() {
    return (customer == null);
}
```

And to bookmark a page:

```
public setBookmark(int pageNumber) {
     this.pageNumber = pageNumber;
}
```

Of course, this is still far from optimal. What if a customer wants to borrow several books? Should the books really hold the reference to the customer? There are several approaches to this. One would be to have a dedicated class that holds the associations of customers to books. Another would be to use some sort of collection in either `Book` or `Customer`. However, that's probably all beyond the scope of your task, so I'll leave it at the above.

---

Comment: Thank You, I thought it could be done just in a single line of code.

Comment: It can: `Book book1 = new Book("Harry Potter", 500, new Customer("Mike", "London"));`

Comment: `Should the books really hold the reference to the customer?` But your examples seems encouraging him to do that.

Comment: As Alexandra seems to be a learner, I thought it was most useful to first resolve the most prominent issue at hand, then give some pointers regarding the other issues. This is most likely a university assignment or tutorial task that focuses on a specific learning goal, I don't think overwhelming her/him now by introducing too many other aspects would be helpful. I basically agree with you, however, which is why I added the note at the end.

Comment: Nice, explanatory answer. Not to be a nit-picker but I would have used "lend" instead of "borrow" and "receiveBack" (or something similar) instead of "giveBack" since they are both methods inside the book.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @theblitz - I'm going to edit accordingly. As a non-native, I *always* get this wrong, hence appreciate the hint.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to declare your instance like this

```
Book book1 = new Book("The Hobbit", 300, "Sarah Connor", "London")
```

You will need to define your constructor of Book Class like this :

```
public Book(String bookName, int pageNumber, String fullname, String address) {
    this.bookName = bookName;
    this.pageNumber = pageNumber;
    this.customer = new Customer(fullname, address);  //I think this needs to be fixed
}
```

Or other option is to declare it like this

```
Book book1 = new Book("The Hobbit", 300, new Customer("Sarah Connor", "London"));
```

Comment: Nice, you covered the one possibility I didn't. However, two issues: `new customer(...` should be `new Customer(...`. Once that's done, you can remove the `//I think this needs to be fixed` comment :)